# Weblogic - JAX-RS Application breaks upon JAX-RS library reference

Tags: java, jax-rs, weblogic12c

I'm having issues with some of my REST applications, whereby some of them break when I reference Jax-rs in their weblogic.xml configuration file, while some of them don't. This is really strange.

In the Weblogic.xml file, I have this:

```
<library-ref>
        <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
        <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
    </library-ref>
```

And the Jax-RS library is installed in my weblogic.

With this referenced, when I try to run a GET request on my browser, I see a "request failed" message.

In the log, I see this:

```
####<Dec 17, 2018 7:24:30 PM WAT> <Error> <HTTP> <Redsvr.africaprudentialregistrars.com> <Main_Server> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '100' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1545071070420> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@614693438[app:eurytus-engine-bonus-req module:eurytus-engine-bonus-req.war path:null spec-version:3.0]] Root cause of ServletException.
A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NullPointerException

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:88)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:864)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:859)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:934)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:925)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:174)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:128)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:65)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:250)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.hasInjectAnnotation(Utilities.java:1478)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findInitializerMethods(Utilities.java:1419)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:102)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:239)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getInitMethods(Utilities.java:246)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:862)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:859)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:934)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:925)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:174)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:128)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:65)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:250)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

I've been trying to figure out what the problem is but nothing.

I'm trying to implement a CORS filter, which won't work without referencing the Jax-rs library.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weblogic I was using at the time needed to be upgraded. Although, I would advise anyone who is interested in building REST services to switch to Spring Boot. It's much lighter, and so much more easier to deal with than hosting a JAX-RS web-service project on Weblogic.